# Display another field in the referenced table for multiple columns with performance issues in mind

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, indexing, bigdata

I have a table of `edge` like this:

```
-------------------------------
| id | arg1 | relation | arg2 |
-------------------------------
| 1  |   1  |     3    |   4  |
-------------------------------
| 2  |   2  |     6    |   5  |
-------------------------------
```

where arg1, relation and arg2 reference to the ids of objects in another `object` table:

```
--------------------
| id | object_name |
--------------------
| 1  |   book      |
--------------------
| 2  |   pen       |
--------------------
| 3  |   on        |
--------------------
| 4  |   table     |
--------------------
| 5  |   bag       |
--------------------
| 6  |   in        |
--------------------
```

What I want to do is that, considering performance issues (a very big table more than 50 million of entries) display the `object_name` for each edge entry rather than `id` such as:

```
---------------------------
| arg1 | relation | arg2  |
---------------------------
| book |    on    | table |
---------------------------
|  pen |    in    | bag   |
---------------------------
```

What is the best select query to do this? Also, I am open to suggestions for optimizing the query - adding more index on the tables etc...

EDIT: Based on the comments below:

1) @Craig Ringer: `PostgreSQL version: 8.4.13` and only index is `id` for both tables.

2) @andrefsp: `edge` is almost x2 times bigger than `object`.

Comment: Any solution is going to invove three index scans of `object` per entry in `edge`. Please show psql `\d` output for both tables so we know what indexes you have, and if possible add your PostgreSQL version and some sample data so everyone doesn't have to dummy up their own data. Follow up with a comment when you're done editing.

Comment: 50mil entries is not a big table. As @CraigRinger asked we would like to see tables definition and `explain analyze` for all queries which you have done so far.

Comment: Which one of the tables is the bigger one?

Comment: Ooops, my bad. I should have included a bit more information as you guys stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't get cheaper than this:

```
SELECT o1.object_name, r1.object_name, o2.object_name
FROM   edge e
JOIN   object o1 ON o1.id = e.arg1
JOIN   object  r ON  r.id = e.relation
JOIN   object o2 ON o2.id = e.arg2;
```

And you don't need more indexes. The one on `object.id` is the only one needed for this query.

But I seriously doubt that you want to retrieve 50 millions of rows at once, and in no particular order. You still didn't give the full picture.

Comment: I surely don't  want to query for 50 millions of rows at once. My program is adding conditional for specific edge rows. This is pretty much the same solution I also came up. I just want to have another opinion on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the structure of the database, you may try to denormalize this part of the database and make table **edge** with fields **id**, **arg1_name**, **relation_name**, **arg2_name**. And keep table **object** without changes to take names for the **edge** table when you insert or update it.

It is not good. Your data will be duplicates (size of the database will be greater) and it may be difficult to insert or update tables.

But it should be fast to select (no JOINs):

```
SELECT arg1_name, relation_name, arg2_name
FROM edge;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ;) However, I don't think I can change the structure of database.

Comment: @israkir: Also, denormalizing a table with 50 million rows would probably make everything slower. Due to the much bigger row size, smaller parts of the table of will reside in cache at any given time. -> fewer cache hits -> more disk access. It really depends on the *medium length* of the strings. If strings are short as in your example, denormalizing could make it faster, but I doubt that's the case. An `integer` occupies 4 bytes, `text` occupies 1 byte + actual string (1 or more bytes per char). You'd have to test to find the sweet spot.